# Could not connect to Endpoint for second peer on Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have my docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  basic:

services:
  ca.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem

      # change the keyfile everytime the generate.sh is used 
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/763ce512db70fbfc91ffcd4ad01d074d3a012ae2488a42dbb1a47a9ce8895de8_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer1rg1
    networks:
      - basic

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/


      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic

      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984

      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb
    networks:
      - basic

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - basic

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx/
    networks:
        - basic
    #depends_on:
    #  - orderer.example.com
    #  - peer0.org1.example.com
    #  - couchdb

  couchdb1:
      container_name: couchdb1
      image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
      environment:
        - COUCHDB_USER=
        - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
      ports:
        - "9984:5984"
      networks:
        - basic

  peer1.org1.example.com:
      container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
      image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
      working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
      command: peer node start
      environment:
        - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
        - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
        - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
        - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
        - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
        - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
        - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
        - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/

        - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic

        - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
        - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984

        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:8051
        #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
        # - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
        # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
        # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
        # - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
        # - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
        # - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
        # - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
      depends_on:
        - orderer.example.com
        - couchdb1
      ports:
        - 8051:8051
      networks:
        - basic
```

When I start the Fabric, all the cointainers correctly goes up but if I insepct with logs the single containers, all seems fine except peer1, who says:

```
2019-07-19 08:05:35.831 UTC [cceventmgmt] HandleChaincodeDeploy -> INFO 03e Channel [mychannel]: Chaincode [Name=traceability, Version=1.0, Hash=[]byte{0xec, 0xe8, 0x2f, 0xd6, 0x66, 0xe8, 0x39, 0x5f, 0x9a, 0xc5, 0x1d, 0x93, 0x7a, 0xed, 0xc6, 0x43, 0xaf, 0xfa, 0xa0, 0xca, 0x4c, 0x99, 0xb4, 0x8b, 0x0, 0x39, 0x2a, 0xdf, 0xfc, 0xea, 0x7e, 0x44}] is not installed hence no need to create chaincode artifacts for endorsement
2019-07-19 08:05:35.850 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 03f [mychannel] Committed block [1] with 1 transaction(s) in 22ms (state_validation=5ms block_commit=6ms state_commit=8ms)
*2019-07-19 08:05:39.546 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 040 Could not connect to Endpoint: 127.0.0.1:7051, InternalEndpoint: 127.0.0.1:7051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded*
2019-07-19 08:05:42.808 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 041 [mychannel] Received block [2] from buffer
2019-07-19 08:05:42.809 UTC [committer.txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 042 [mychannel] Validated block [2] in 0ms
2019-07-19 08:05:42.835 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 043 [mychannel] Committed block [2] with 1 transaction(s) in 26ms (state_validation=3ms block_commit=8ms state_commit=13ms)
*2019-07-19 08:06:07.547 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 044 Could not connect to Endpoint: 127.0.0.1:7051, InternalEndpoint: 127.0.0.1:7051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded*
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?
I think it is some problem related to the configuration of my docker-compose file but I don't know what's wrong, I see different configuration on the web.

These are my containers up:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
d99aec3ed5b0        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-traceability-1.0-76b4798b7a60d0b2659c39b86072164c35face709e8536003ba90ad0d0211f7c   "chaincode -peer.add…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                                                         dev-peer0.org1.example.com-traceability-1.0
1f2ec12ac129        hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                                       "/bin/bash"              6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                                                         cli
deb0d9f11159        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                        "peer node start"        6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
fc9b07f9d487        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                        "peer node start"        6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8051->8051/tcp                           peer1.org1.example.com
aad71ba93cc1        hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                                     "orderer"                6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
8f73d314f8ec        hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                          "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.example.com
89af426d3101        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                                     "tini -- /docker-ent…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
aff4a66215a1        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                                     "tini -- /docker-ent…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9984->5984/tcp       couchdb1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try with the following changes & up the docker again -**

```
 peer0.org1.example.com : 
        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
        - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

**with**

```
peer0.org1.example.com :
    - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
    - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

**and in**

```
peer1.org1.example.com :
 - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
 - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:8051
```

**with**

```
peer1.org1.example.com :
    - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
    - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
```

Comment: I did what you say but I still get:
2019-07-19 08:56:33.714 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 042 Could not connect to Endpoint: 127.0.0.1:7051, InternalEndpoint: 127.0.0.1:7051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded

Comment: Request 127.0.0.1:7051 in firefox, and check if you are getting any response or not.. ?

Comment: On the browser I don't, but as you can see with docker ps the container is listening on that port. I have edited and inserted my containers above.

Comment: It means, peer port is not open,thatswhy you are facing such issue, if port would open , you will get the response on telnet/firefox.

Comment: refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56871941/error-while-sending-query-request-from-client-no-peer-available-to-query/56879876#56879876

Comment: Hi @Artho let's say if I start a single peer at the beginning with only `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT` defined to point to its external endpoint. How shall I configure the other variables then, in this case, while adding new peer nodes to the same organization? Also, let's say that the given `peer0` is also an anchor peer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a small typo in the docker-compose file.

in the **peer1** section the `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT` should set to the peers own address i.e `peer1.org1.example.com:8051` instead of `peer0.org1.com:8051`. can you correct that see if its working,if not then do comment.